# CURL PHP возвращает обрезанную строку json при GET запросе

Tags: php, json, curl, get

Столкнулся с проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить.

Я пытаюсь получить GET запросом json строку с API используя CURL PHP

```
    $url = 'https://api.egamersworld.com/counterstrike/bets';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

На веб сервере (хостинг) происходит странное - я получаю урезанный вариант этой json строки, урезается по разному на 20%-40%. Протестировал на двух разных хостингах, всё тоже самое

**Но на локальном сервере/в Postman всё работает как надо и json строка возвращается полной**

Пример

1. На локальном сервере я получаю json string(649987)
2. В Postman я получаю json string(649987)
3. На хосте я получаю **string(553522)**

В чем может быть проблема? Подозреваю что в каких-то лимитах на стороне самих хостов, но перебрал всю инфу в интернете и не нашел ничего

Comment: определитесь, вам все же возвращается валидный контент но разной длины, либо битый json ? попробуйте через `file_get_contents` получить.

Comment: @teran

возвращается валидный контнет, но разной длины (в данном случае на хостинге он урезан) - через file_get_contents тоже урезается

Comment: попробуйте с заголовками юзер-агента поколдовать

Comment: @teran

Попробовал, помимпо user-agent выставил cookies - тоже не дало результата.
Мне кажется, если бы дело было в них - на локальном хосте я бы не смог получать корректный json

Comment: если бы только в них, то да. Вы сравнили вообще файлы то? мб вам эта разница в выдаче не критична вообще

Comment: @teran

там теряется половина данных при обработки ответа

Comment: коли ответ пришел целиком (валидный json), значит сервер отдает не данные на основании каких-то проверок. Возможно, например, вы часто слали запросы, и вас (IP) в какой-нить черный список занесли. Попробуйте обратиться в суппорт сервиса, мб там прояснят, почему так.